# When is it appropriate to assign values to an instance variable in Java?

Tags: java, oop, instance-variables

This is a question on best practice. When taking an object oriented approach, I've come up with three different ways that I might do the same thing. To my untrained eye, none of them seem "wrong", but I know every language and style has its best practices, and I want to know if any of these three ways violate some "best practice" that I haven't learned yet.

Way 1: (declare, then assign in constructor)

```
public class CCipher {

    private String alphabet;
    private String shiftedAlphabet;
    private int mainKey;

    public CCipher(int key){

        mainKey = key;
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(mainKey) 
                        + alphabet.substring(0, mainKey);
    }
```

Way 2: (declare and assign at the same time)

```
public class CCipher {

    private String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private String shiftedAlphabet;
    private int mainKey;

    public CCipher(int key){

        mainKey = key;
        shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(mainKey) 
                        + alphabet.substring(0, mainKey);
    }
```

Way 3: (Some things get initialized in a non get/set method)

```
public class CCipher {

    private String alphabet;
    private String shiftedAlphabet;
    private int mainKey;

    public CCipher(int key){

        mainKey = key;
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    }

    public String encrypt(String input){
        shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(mainKey) 
                        + alphabet.substring(0, mainKey);
        // ... code to encrypt input ...
    }

    public String decrypt(String input){
        shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(26 - mainKey) 
                + alphabet.substring(0, 26 - mainKey);
        // ... code to decrypt input
    }
}
```

Personally, for this specific homework assignment, I really like the third way best, because it flows with the logic of the problem I'm trying to solve. But it it's wrong, well it's wrong...

Comment: Your third method leaves `shiftedAlphabet` as `null` when the `CCipher` object is initialized; this may end up causing issues for whoever uses it and expects the value to not be `null`. The other two are mostly personal preference.

Comment: For the third way, the `shiftedAlphabet` is only ever used internally in the method which assigns to it, so there is no need for it to be a field; better to make it a local variable.

Comment: Why dont you declare `alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` as `private static final String`? Is there any chance it changes later?

Comment: Do you need to have a mainKey field in the first place? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere except in the constructor.

Comment: Hi @NickAth, I doubt it would change later unless I spontaneously learn Russian. I haven't learned about "final" yet, though my IDE has been poking me to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version seems okay. But with the constant indeed as static final String.

```
public class CCipher {

    private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private final String shiftedAlphabet;
    private final int mainKey;

    public CCipher(int key) {
        mainKey = key;
        shiftedAlphabet = ALPHABET.substring(mainKey) 
                        + ALPHABET.substring(0, mainKey);
    }
```

---

Christopher Schneider pointed out that in for encrypting and decrypting different shiftedAlphabets are used. As a CCipher object in reality probably either encrypts or decrypts, make it a local variable.

One would need two different non-final lazily initialized fields which is cumbersome.

```
public class CCipher {

    private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //private final String shiftedEncryptAlphabet;
    //private final String shiftedDecryptAlphabet;
    private final int mainKey;

    public CCipher(int key) {
        mainKey = key;
        shiftedAlphabet = ALPHABET.substring(mainKey) 
                        + ALPHABET.substring(0, mainKey);
    }

    public String encrypt(String input){
        String shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(mainKey) 
                    + alphabet.substring(0, mainKey);
        // ... code to encrypt input ...
    }

    public String decrypt(String input){
        String shiftedAlphabet = alphabet.substring(26 - mainKey) 
            + alphabet.substring(0, 26 - mainKey);
        // ... code to decrypt input
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. If properties don't change, mark them `final` and initialize in the constructor.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider indeed. Even in 3 the mainKey seems to be fixed. Hence prepare the constants so everything is optimal.

Comment: I missed this, since it's a class property and not a local variable, but looks like `shiftedAlphabet` is a changing variable. What it should probably be is two variables, e.g. `shiftedAlphabetEncrypt` and `Decrypt`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I oversaw that. Then a local variable maybe would be best, as it is unlikely that the same instance would do both, encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thanks. I'm thinking of using a combination of all your answers. Keep `alphabet` and make it final. Get rid of the shiftedAlphabet variable and make it local. Let the `mainKey` be filled in by the constructor...

Answer (score 1):

With regard to `alphabet` - it if never changes, the second snippet probably comes closest to the best practice, but it's still not quite there - it should be a `private static final` "constant":

```
public class CCipher {   
    private static final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    // ...
}
```

With regard to `shiftedAlphabet` - the third snippet is definitely less favorable (albeit not technically "wrong") - on each call to `encrypt` or `decrypt` you recalculate the `shiftedAlphabet` which is not impacted by the `input` in any way. It may not be wrong, but it is wasteful (in other words - as a teacher, I'd definitely deduce points for that, even if the code does work).

To sum this up - the second snippet is probably the best of all three, but I'd fix `alphabet`'s modifiers to `private static final`.

Comment: Well, it's not being "re-calculated" necessarily, seeing as how it never got initialized in the constructor or when it was declared. That's why I like this way, because each decrypt requires on shifted alphabet and encrypt requires a totally different shifted alphabet . Perhaps the solution (from a comment on the question) would be to just make shiftedAlphabet a local variable in the methods that use it?

Comment: And I haven't learned about "final" yet, though my IDE has been poking me to use it with a warning highlight. I wanted to hold off, but since you mention it I'll skip ahead a little :)

Comment: @rocksNwaves most readers, me included, missed the fact that your third example shows that you actually need two different versions of the shifted alphabet: one for decryption, and one for encryption. So use two local variables, or use two (final) fields. But don't use a single field and change the value every time one of the methods is invoked. That makes the code not-thread-safe, and extremely confusing.

Comment: @JBNizet That makes sense to me! That's what I'm going to do now, thank you!